# How to implement Authorize filters by Roles on JsonResults method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

I need help on how to authorize the access of **JsonResults** methods by roles. I have sample codes below using custom authorize filter attribute and it works fine with **ActionResults** and **PartialViewResults** methods but not with the
JsonResults. I want to find a way that if the role name has no access on that JsonResults method, it should be redirected
to the Unauthorized page or just don't execute somehow and if it has access then it should execute the method, 
but in this case, it's not behaving that way. It won't execute the JsonResult method even though the role has 
access on it. How do I resolve this type of scenario?
Thanks...Below are the codes I used

```
public class RedirectUnauthorizedRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {         
            if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "Error", Action = "Unauthorised" }));
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine using this

```
[RedirectUnauthorizedRoles(Roles = "MANAGER, ADMIN, SUPPORT")]  
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

but not on this one below

```
[RedirectUnauthorizedRoles(Roles = "MANAGER, ADMIN, SUPPORT")]  
public JsonResult GetSpecialData(string param1)
{
 // statement here...
}
```

Comment: If its a `JsonResult` it suggests your using ajax to call that method, and ajax calls cannot redirect (the whole point of them is to stay in the same page)

Comment: yes, you're right but what I want to happen is to execute the JsonResult method if the role has an access to it. Right now, it won't execute the method so it returns null.

Comment: What happens when you just apply the standard `[Authorize(Roles = "..")]` attribute?

Comment: So, if I use the standard Authorize attribute, it will keep prompting an "Authentication required" alert on the web page to log in your username and password and even though I log in the username and password, it still keeps on prompting.

Comment: That makes no sense if you are already logged in. What happens when you just navigate to that method via the address bar?

Comment: If you do force browsing on the address bar of the using the url of that JsonResult method...It still behaving the same. Would still prompt you an alert.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering...if you apply it to the JsonResult it won't recognize the Roles in the attribute but it works perfectly with ActionResults.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @timmack in RedirectUnauthorizedRoles Filter i have returned JsonResult. if user is valid then we are going to return "1" as value and if User is invalid then we are going to return "0" to Ajax Method , i hope it may help you.

> Filter

```
public class RedirectUnauthorizedRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {

           //Example if User is Valid then i will return 1 else it will return 0
            var value = true ? "1" : "0";

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = value
            };
        }
    }
}
```

> Ajax Method

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function demox() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Controller/ActionMethod',
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'token': 'Demo' },
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    if (result === "0")
                    {
                        alert("Not Authorized");
                        return window.location.href = "/Error/Error";
                    }

                    return window.location.href = "/ValidPage URL";
                },
                error: function (err)
                {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```